# Manipulating data from a JSON feed to display it

Tags: php, json

```
{
  "Group": [
    {
      "name": "HolderOne",
      "operators": [
          {
           "username": "ken",
           "status": 3
          },
         .....etc.....
```

The JSON feed I am attempting to manipulate has to format above.

I wish to be able to display username and status.

```
$json = file_get_contents("urlhere");
$obj=json_decode($json);
echo $obj->username;
echo $obj->status;
```

This obviously doesn't work as they are nested(?) within the feed...I have tried:

```
$obj->Group[0]->name->operators->username
```

and

```
$obj->Group[0]->name->username
```

to no avail (as well as json_decode with ,true and ['name'], etc).

Am I being particularly dim?

when I do a var dump, the data is being collected from the feed okay.

Comment: $obj->Group[0]->name->operators[0]->username ? Looks like operators is an array of objects too...

Comment: Have you also tried to `print_r($obj)` or `var_dump($obj)`? That also helps a lot...

Comment: Trying using $obj->Group[0]->name->operators[0]->username

Comment: For a visualized JSON and traversal tips see [array.i-o](http://array.include-once.org/?foreach=1&assoc=&json=%7B%0D%0A++%22Group%22%3A+%5B%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++%22name%22%3A+%22HolderOne%22%2C%0D%0A++++++%22operators%22%3A+%5B%0D%0A++++++++++%7B%0D%0A+++++++++++%22username%22%3A+%22ken%22%2C%0D%0A+++++++++++%22status%22%3A+3%0D%0A++++++++++%7D%0D%0A++++++%5D%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++%5D%0D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to figure this out is to iteratively do `print_r`'s:

```
print_r($obj)
//prints what you see above
print_r($obj['Group']
//prints the Group Object
print_r($obj['Group'][0])
//prints first element in Group Object
print_r($obj['Group'][0]['operators'])
//etc.....
```

That's how I find out how to access these *deep* elements if I get a little stuck.  Though it appears to me that you want:

`$obj->Group[0]->operators[0]->username`

Comment: Cheers.....If I wanted to grab the username value and interrogate it against a variable value (e.g. if KEN = KEN then...else...), would this be PHP or JSON? i.e. would print_r be the way? BTW - really appreciate the help so thank-you! :0)

Comment: `print_r` is really **never** useful to for your application in prodution, it's really just for development so you can see what's in various variables.  JSON is just a format to store data, PHP is a language that you write applications in, so PHP is your answer.

Comment: Thanks Landon - apart from `print_r` data doesn't outpuyt - a vardump works, but a PHP `echo` doesn't..then to additionally complicate things I wish to say if a particular user name is X, display the status

Comment: Aha got it working (Thanks landon) - the problem I have now is with foreach so I can say for each array, if username is x display the status.