# PHP - How to echo Value from Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have:

```
$request = Array
(
    [ID] => 2264
    [SUCCESS] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [MESSAGE] => Service Details
                    [LIST] => Array
                        (
                            [retail_name] => 
                            [credit_admin] => FREE
                            [credit] => 0
                            [discount_admin] => 0
                            [discount] => 0
                            [cartdiscount] => 0
```

If I do:

```
echo $request[ID];                            // it says: 2264
echo $request[SUCCESS];                       // it says: Array
echo $request[SUCCESS][0][MESSAGE];           // it says: Service Details
```

But I need to echo "credit" and if I do:

```
echo $request[SUCCESS][0][LIST];           // I get ERROR
echo $request[SUCCESS][0][LIST][credit];   // I get ERROR
```

I dont understand why? How can I do it?
Thank you

Comment: Try as `echo $request['SUCCESS'][0]['LIST']['credit'];` if it won't work post your error too

Comment: Check this post it may help you to debug it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13018280/manipulating-data-from-a-json-feed-to-display-it

Comment: @Uchiha Thank you, that worked!!! Hmm.. So always should use ' ?

Comment: Yes I personally always prefer quotes and it can be `"` or `'`

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia please consider to write your comment as an Answer or upvote/downvote answers below so I can mark this question as Solved. Thank you so much for all your great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previously every string without quotes was treated like string if there was no Constant defined under this name, but from `PHP 7.2` now issues error of level `E_WARNING`. [Why is $foo[bar] wrong?](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.donts)

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant test - assumed 'test' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

In this example list is treated as construct [`list()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php). Using bare strings in associative arrays as keys is deprecated and should be avoided.

Correct way is to call it with quotes (single or double):

```
echo $request['SUCCESS'][0]['LIST'];
echo $request['SUCCESS'][0]['LIST']['credit'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't using quotes to specify the array keys. you should use `['ID']` instead of `[ID]`

PHP fixes this for you and presumes you meant `['ID']` instead of `[ID]` and trows a notice in the logs

This doen't work for `[LIST]` however because `LIST` is a reserved keyword. That means that `list` has a function in PHP. PHP doesn't know which one you need and doesn't return result.

Change `[LIST]` to `['LIST']` and you should recieve your values.
Please learn to use arrays with quotes, to prevent errors like this in the future

Comment: **List** is not really a function, but a language construct. [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) is used to assign a list of variables in one operation.

Comment: @Uchiha : That is why I mentioned it has a function within PHP not that it is a function in PHP ;)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on Your `Key` and `Value`

If your array key has a value it will directly output that

> for ex

```
 echo $request[ID];
```

b'coz  id directly holds a value;

But

```
$request[SUCCESS]; 

// holds an array. you cannot echo a array directly 
// to do something like this you will need the key of your inner 
// array with outer array in combinations to echo the values
```

> for ex

```
 echo $request[SUCCESS][0]['MESSAGE'];
```

// Key "O" holds an array also. so you need to use its inner array keys

same needs to be done for

```
 echo $request[SUCCESS][0]['MESSAGE']['LIST']['credit_admin']; 
 // where again list is a array
```